# How to retieve a excel file from sql database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, excel

I'm using bootstrap in my application.I'm storing a excel file in sql db.

here is my code;

**Default.aspx**

```
 <div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">
   Upload</label>
  <div class="controls">
   <input id="fileupload" type="file" runat="server"/>
  </div>
 </div>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click"  />
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/");
            HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;

            if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            }          
            if (hfc.Count != 0)
            {
                string contenttype = String.Empty;

                    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];

                    string fileExtn = Path.GetExtension(hfc[i].FileName).ToLower();

                    if (fileExtn == ".xls" || fileExtn == ".xlsx" || fileExtn == ".xlmx")
                    {                      
                        switch (fileExtn)
                        {

                            case ".xls":

                                contenttype = "application/excel";

                                break;

                            case ".xlsx":

                                contenttype = "application/excel";

                                break;

                            case ".xlmx":

                                contenttype = "application/excel";

                                break;
                        }

                        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            string SPfilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/");
                            string filepath = SPfilePath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                            hpf.SaveAs(filepath);                                                       
                            string ContentType = hpf.ContentType;
                            int fileLen = hpf.ContentLength;
                            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileLen - 1];
                            hpf.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                             byte[] Data = fileBytes;                     
                        }
                       new DefaultManager().SaveFile(Data , fileLen ,filepath ,ContentType );
                }
            }
            UploadMsg = auditmgr.AddClientAuditReport(, audit);         
        }
    }
```

Here im saving `ContentType` as `varchar(256)`,`filepath`  as `varchar(256)`, `fileLen`  as `int`,`Data`  as `varchar(max)` in db. It is getting added in db. but I don't know how to retrieve that excel file from db .

Im storing that excel file in bytes in SQL db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DataTable dtReport = GetDataFromDatabase(fileID: 20);     
 Response.Clear();
 Response.Buffer = true;
 Response.ContentType = Path.GetExtension(dtReport["FileName"]).ToString();
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Path.GetFileName(dtReport["FileName"]).ToString());
 Response.ContentType = Path.GetExtension(dtReport["FileName"]).ToString();
 Response.Charset = "";
 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
 Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dtReport["Data"]);
 Response.End();
```

Comment: If you are using asp.net then also add "ASP.NET" tag with your question

Answer (score 0):

First change datatype for "Data as varchar(max)" to varbinary(max) then save file content in database

//for retrival file from database you can use this code

```
DataTable dt = GetFileDetailFromDatabase(fileID: 20); // here you select data from database, for Ex. fileID is 20

string strpath = @"C:\Download\" + dt.Rows[0]["FileName"].ToString(); // if you are storing file name(Only file name with extension not full file path) in database other wise give any temp file name with same extension which file had at the time of save in database

FileStream flStrm = new FileStream(strpath, FileMode.Create);
Byte[] Buffer = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
flStrm.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
flStrm.Close();
Buffer = null;
```